# Return json from python

Tags: python, json, drupal

I have a simple module in Drupal that is expecting 4 values in JSON from a python script. I believe the python script is collecting the data I need just fine:

```
 # information is easy to get via xpath from html ids
tree = etree.HTML(tree)
make = tree.xpath('//div[@id="makeData"]')[0]
model = tree.xpath('//div[@id="modelData"]')[0]
manufacture_year = tree.xpath('//div[@id="manufactureYearData"]')[0]
engine_size = tree.xpath('//div[@id="engineSizeData"]')[0]
```

Now I need to return that data so the Drupal module can catch it with this:

```
  // Execute the script and store the output in a variable
$py_output = shell_exec($cmd);

// Assuming the output is a JSON string.
$data = drupal_json_decode($py_output);
```

I don't know python, but some searching around lead me to try this:

```
return json.dumps({'make': make,
                   'model': model,
                   'year': year,
                   'engine': engine})
```

That doesn't seem to work. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Your shell exec thing is probably expecting data from stdout... Then you should `print(json.dumps(...))`

Comment: Did you try running the python script standalone? You have a syntax error if that `return` is outside a function : )

Comment: I've tried the print(json... syntax instead of return - still not getting what I expected. Also, Tomas, as embarrassing as this is, I know nothing about python - including how to execute the script alone. My Drupal module seems to send the variable like this: $cmd = '/car_data_check.py ' . $plate_number;  Can I do that from a Unix terminal?